# Can I magically make the selectors non-functional if the selection value is empty?

Tags: javascript, selector

Background:
I have a function that I call like this:

```
hide_modules('string1','string2');
```

The function is something like:

```
function hide_modules(param1,param2) {
       MM.getModules()
         .withClass(param1)
         .exceptWithClass(param2)
         .enumerate(function(module) {
           module.hide(
             // some other code
           );
         });
}
```

Most of the time I call the function with values as shown above.
Sometimes I do not want 'string1' to have a value and I'd like the my function to not use that first selector, effectively like this:

```
   MM.getModules()
     // .withClass(param1)
     .exceptWithClass(param2)
     .enumerate(function(module) {
       module.hide(
         // some other code
       );
     });
```

I've tried just calling it with an empty string, 0, false as param1 but the end result class selection is not what I want.
Sometimes I also call it with param2 empty and not wanting to have the param2 related selector used either.

So the question is:
Without writing a big if-then-else statement, is there some fancy way I can make those selectors non-functional (the equivalent of commenting it out like above) when the param1 and/or param2 values are not specified?

---

The supporting code that my function calls is provided for me in a 3rd party library that I can't change. I include some of the relevant parts here as it may help with the answer:

```
var withClass = function (className) {
    return modulesByClass(className, true);
};
var modulesByClass = function (className, include) {
    var searchClasses = className;
    if (typeof className === "string") {
        searchClasses = className.split(" ");
    }

    var newModules = modules.filter(function (module) {
        var classes = module.data.classes.toLowerCase().split(" ");

        for (var c in searchClasses) {
            var searchClass = searchClasses[c];
            if (classes.indexOf(searchClass.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
                return include;
            }
        }

        return !include;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since js doesn't supports function overloading, the only way is to validate your parameters inside your method. Check for `truthy` and ternary operator will do the trick

```
      var modules = MM.getModules();
      modules = param1 ? modules.withClass(param1) : modules;
      modules = param2 ? modules.exceptWithClass(param2) : modules;
      modules.enumerate(function(module) {
      module.hide(
         // some other code
       );
     });
```

> to skip first parameter

```
hide_modules(null,'string2');
```

> to skip second parameter

```
hide_modules('string1');
```

Comment: Ok, I think I've implemented what you suggested but now I am getting an error.

Here is my full function now:

    `function(hideClasses,exceptClasses) {
     var modules=MM.getModules();
     modules = hideClasses && modules.withClass(hideClasses);
     modules = exceptClasses && modules.exceptWithClass(exceptClasses);
     modules.enumerate(function(module) {
       module.hide( // some code
     );
     });
     },`

Comment: MMM-Face-Reco-DNN.js:240 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'exceptWithClass' of null
    at Class.hide_modules (MMM-Face-Reco-DNN.js:240)
    at Class.notificationReceived (MMM-Face-Reco-DNN.js:371)
    at sendNotification (main.js:96)
    at main.js:64

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. I can't seem to get it right, but line 240 is `modules = exceptClasses && modules.exceptWithClass(exceptClasses);` and I am calling the function like: `hide_modules(null,this.config.classes_noface)`